# traverse array sent from bash, in external awk script

Tags: arrays, bash, awk

In my bash script I have:

```
patterns=( "somee? +pattern" "Another +here" )

awk -v l="$line" -f horsepower <(printf '%s\n' "${patterns[@]}") <<<"$stdout"
```

, so sending to `awk` script two files, first being process substitution output of
`printf` on `${patterns[@]}` array, and second being **HERESTRING** feed from
`$stdout` variable.

, then in that external `awk` script, named here `horsepower` I have the
following:

```
BEGIN {
    ...some initialization, not of importance for this question
}


# while reading first file, populate `patterns` array in awk
FNR==NR { patterns[$0]=""; next }

for (pat in patterns)
    # match lines from `$stdout` on patterns sent from bash, and save them in `a_rem`
    # array, for later output in END block.
    $0 ~ pat { a_rem[NR]=$0 }

# then follows END block
END {
    ...also non important
}
```

, but I am given notice about syntax error on `for` from above `for (pat in
patterns)`.

What am I doing wrong? Also, is `awk` getting correct first, second files from
my bash script, using that method of `<()`, and `<<<"$stdout"`?

I have to mention, all of this was working when I was using literal regexes in
`awk` script, but the moment I introduced that `for (pat in patterns)`, and
adding that `<()` in bash(`<<<"$stdout"` was ok!), I am getting this syntax
error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least two problems, one at shell level, one at the `awk` level.

#### Shell

A program like `awk` won't read standard input if you give it another file to read.  The process substitution `<(...)` gives it one file to read.  To get it to read standard input too, you need:

```
awk -f program <(...) - <<<"$stdout"
```

#### Awk

The pattern/action language applies at the source level.  You're trying to apply it dynamically to the list of patterns you read.  You'll need to modify the code that reads:

```
for (pat in patterns)
    # match lines  on patterns sent from bash, and save them in `a_rem`
    # array, for later output in END block.
    $0 ~ pat { a_rem[NR]=$0 }
```

so that it is more like:

```
{
    for (pat in patterns)
        if ($0 ~ pat) { a_rem[NR]=$0; break }
}
```

The added `break` is an optimization so that you don't add a single line multiple times to the same element of the array.

Comment: What should I search for, to learn more about this (_dynamically applying to the list of patterns_)? And question about `break`, is it for not to repeat same line, only for the time being in that very same line?

Comment: There's nothing much wrong with what you did that 10 years of experience won't fix. I learned much of this stuff so long ago that the way I learned is simply not relevant today (hint: there wasn't a WWW to search back then). That said, for `awk`, the GNU [`gawk`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/) manual is pretty good. There is an O'Reilly book on [`awk` and `sed`](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565922259.do); there is also a [book](http://www.amazon.com/The-AWK-Programming-Language-Alfred/dp/020107981X) by Messrs Aho, Weinberger and Kernighan, whose initials you might recognize.

Comment: Regarding `break`: suppose there are ten patterns, and a particular line matches five of those patterns.  Then the code without the `break` will store `$0` into `a_rem[NR]` 5 times, whereas the code with `break` will store it just once.  Further, it will stop on the first match, so it will do fewer matching operations when the line matches (in general -- unless the last pattern is the only one to match) and again saves effort by the computer.  Modern computers are fast; this is likely a second order effect, especially if you have many patterns and few of them are ever matched.

Comment: So if more than one pattern matches here, I will have the first match in order, as others would override that `a_rem[NR]` value, because of the index **NR** not being changed, right?

Comment: Well, neither `$0` (what you are storing) nor `NR` (where you are storing) changes, so you'd copy the same material multiple times.  Note that you will, in general, have a sparse array because not every line will match.  If you wanted a copy of the line every time you matched, then you'd use something like `a_rem[n++] = $0` (probably with the `break`). If you need to know which pattern matched the line, then you have to save that as well (`a_pat[NR] = pat`, or `a_pat[n] = pat`, but be careful where you increment `n`). It's a programming language; you can do lots of variations very easily.

Comment: Yes I know, but I'm ok with sparse array because I need to render lines where matches were found, in my END block, so there I do `for (r in a_rem)...`

Comment: As long as you're aware that the elements need not be served in any specific order, that's fine.